# Why does an attempted export of a plugin fragment "not find the exported unit"?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing a plugin fragment named JunitGenerationFragment.  I can test it using Launch an Eclipse application, and everything works fine.

I try to export using the 3 steps on the Exporting section of the manifest's Overview tab.  When using the Export Wizard, I choose to install into a particular directory.

[image: deploy fragment]

I get a Problems Occurred dialog that says "Could not find the exported unit with id..."

[image: plugin not found]

As far as I can tell, the directories have the appropriate content.

[image: install dir]

[image: plugin dir]

However, if I try to install from that site, "There are no items available".

[image: no items available]

How can I successfully make this plugin fragment available from the export repository?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there was some kind of file system problem?  Additional attempts to export the repository to the `C:\Tools\Eclipse\workspace2019-06\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\install` directory failed.  However, I could export to another directory.

Later, I renamed the original `C:\Tools\Eclipse\workspace2019-06\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\install` directory to something else and retried an export to `C:\Tools\Eclipse\workspace2019-06\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\install`.  This time it succeeded, and I could load the plugin from that repository.

Update:  The renaming "solution" does not seem to be repeatable.  A repeat attempt to use the Export Wizard to exprort to `C:\Tools\Eclipse\workspace2019-06\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\install` fails, as in the original problem description.  Renaming the directory again did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your workspace .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\install directory and restart eclipse.